# Is it possible to use R as a "standalone" invisible computational backend in Excel?

Tags: r, excel, com, rexcel, vba

I know it is possible to integrate R with Excel using packages such as RExcel,but is it possible to use R as a "standalone" invisible computational backend in Excel? For example, my objective is to create statistical programs that use Excel as a front end and leverage R packages in the back end for statistical computations. I would like users to be able to use the Excel workbooks without having to install R.

Comment: SQL Server 2016 [supports in-database R services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604845.aspx). I can't imaging it would be hard to leverage from Excel using ADO. I haven't played with it yet so I don't know if the [R Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/microsoft-r-getting-started#microsoft-r-client) is COM visible or not.

Comment: Try `XLConnect` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html

Comment: XLConnect allows you to work FROM R into excel workbooks. It does NOT allow you to control R through an excel worksheet.